# Unable to enable filestream in sqlserver ubuntu

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql server in ubuntu. I am trying to enable filestream so that I can use filestream in my existing db. But I am unable to do so. I couldn't install SSMS as it is not available for Ubuntu. I tried the below commands using sqlcmd but it doesn't seem to have any effect as I am still getting error when I try to add a filestream to my db.

```
use DB
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options'
GO
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2
GO
```

I am trying since past 6 hours and couldn't get any link related to ubuntu. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refering to the documetation on [SQL Server on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2017?view=sql-server-2017#Unsupported) tells you why. For the database engine, the following features are unsupported on Linux:

- Transactional replication
- Merge replication
- Change Data Capture (see SQL Server Agent)
- Stretch DB
- PolyBase
- Distributed query with 3rd-party connections
- Linked Servers to data sources other than SQL Server
- System extended stored procedures (XP_CMDSHELL, etc.)
- **Filetable, FILESTREAM**
- CLR assemblies with the EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE permission set
- Buffer Pool Extension

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I did not go thru the documentation. I need to check for other options.

Comment: There are a lot of limitations with SQL Server on Linux, @SathiyaNarayanan , as it's a effectively a new venture for Microsoft. If you are using it then you definitely need to review what you can (or more specifically can't) do before you commit to using it.